# How to get first value of textbox with change event using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have textbox with value binded from database. I have onkeyup event in the textbox. I want to make calculation like old value plus new value. Is there a function that can get textbox value after page load using javascript?

e.g. First value while page load is 5
when I change textbox to 3, then label value would be 8
when I change textbox again to 4, then label value would be 9.

Comment: Please update the question with some code that you have tried....

Comment: @Mamun I have no idea to get it right. If you have clue what function or syntax I can use to get first value, I'll be thankfull.

Comment: You can store old value in localstorage in javascript when page load or event has fire then you can calculate with new value and when new value is set again update localstorage value.. this will help you `localStorage.setItem("oldvalue", "3");` and you can get value like `localStorage.getItem("oldvalue");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data` attribute and set the default value in it. Then use `onchange` event listener and once the focus is removed from  the input it will get the default value and the new value. Use `parseInt` to convert string to number before adding

```js
function updateValue(e) {
  let defaultVal = e.target.dataset.val;
  let newVal = e.target.value;
  e.target.value = parseInt(defaultVal, 10) + parseInt(newVal, 10)
}
```

```html
<input type='text' value='5' data-val='5' onchange='updateValue(event)'>
```

Comment: I'm using asp textbox and onkeyup event. Will this work? I've tried, but nothing happen.

Comment: @nia put a debugger or log statement inside the function and see if that is triggering

Comment: thanks a lot. really appreciated. I've get it right now. Sorry, I can't upvote your answer because I'm a new member

Answer (score 2):

You have to preserve the original value in a data attribute in addition to knowing the actual `value`.  For example:

```html
<input id="my-text-box" type="text" data-original-value="5" value="5">
```

Then you can access the original value via jQuery:

```
$('#my-text-box').data().originalValue;
```

or in plain JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('my-text-box');
var originalValue = element.getAttribute("data-original-value");
```

and the new value with jQuery:

```
$('#my-text-box').val();
```

or in plain JavaScript:

```
var element = document.getElementById('my-text-box');
var originalValue = element.value;
```

EDIT: for plain JavaScript answers.

Comment: As the question is not tagged for jQuery, and the question does not mention using it, it's better to assume that jQuery will not be used and give an answer that does not require adding third party libraries.

Comment: I updated my answer with plain JavaScript examples.  Thank you for the critique.

Comment: @DavidKlinge Thanks. Sorry, I already mark brk's as answer and I can't upvote your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text input with an `id` of `my-text-input`, and a variable called `originalValue`:

```
window.onload( function() {
 originalValue = document.getElementById('my-text-input').value 
});
```